# Scala - Shift element pairs in a list

Tags: scala, list

I am starting with Scala and I want to code a function that shifts element pairs in a list like so:

> changePairs(List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11))
>
> //> res62: List[Int] = List(2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 5, 8, 7, 10, 9, 11)

I thought about spliting the list in two, reverse the values and then join the list again, but I can't reverse the values, I only managed to reverse the whole list:

```
 def changePairs(a: List[Int]) = {
     val listAux = a zip a.tail
     val listAux2 = listAux.reverse
}
```

> //> res6: List[(Int, Int)] = List((10,11), (9,10), (8,9), (7,8), (6,7),
>   (5,6), (4,5), (3,4), (2,3), (1,2))

Does anyone know how can I manage to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it, using `grouped`:

```
list.grouped(2).flatMap(_.reverse).toList
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Comment: Both `map` and `flatten`? Wouldn't it be handy if we had the ability to do both at once. ;-)